# renew value of performWithDelay math.random

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can i renew the value of math.random every second?

```
tmrSpawn = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(9, 50), spawnBC3, 0)
```

it selects 1 between 9/50 (and stays that value) but i want it to refresh this  value every time, any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your **spawnBC3** function:

```
local function spawnBC3()

    -- your code here

    if(tmrSpawn == nil) then
        tmrSpawn = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(9, 50), spawnBC3)
    else
        timer.cancel( tmrSpawn )
    end
end

--here we start the timer first time
local tmrSpawn = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(9, 50), spawnBC3)
```